# rails error on macos mojave 10.14.5: config/load_config.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- configurate (LoadError)

Tags: macos, mojave, ruby, rails

Im trying to install ruby and rails on macos using rbenv.

On running `rails new myapp` and `rails -v`

it gives error:

```
5: from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
4: from bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
3: from /Users/jagtarsingh/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2: from /Users/jagtarsingh/config/boot.rb:8:in `require_relative'
1: from /Users/jagtarsingh/config/load_config.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'/Users/jagtarsingh/config/load_config.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- configurate (LoadError)
```

Im following these sources

http://guides.railsgirls.com/install#setup-for-os-x
https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave

I don't have a good search term that can help me figure out this error. Where might I start to research or diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

That guide is very polished and super close to getting you an install, but I fear it isn't sufficient to get rails running.

The two things I've been able to reproduce is the `rbenv` isn't calling the proper version of gem to get rails installed and even after you rehash things, rails is still being called from /usr/bin and not where `homebrew` and `rbenv` are stashing the non-system version of these tools.

To check which location in your PATH the key tools are being called:

```
which ruby gem rails rbenv
```

On a clean system, you would see this:

```
$ which ruby gem rails rbenv
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/gem
/usr/bin/rails
```

After following that instructions, your gem is still not calling the /usr/local version so you're installing rails against the system framework and not the intended one. I don't have a full solution yet, but this might help someone that knows how to search for the `gem` command to get us both other this error in the install guide and not have to pick apart the scripts to figure what other steps are needed.

Comment: $ which ruby gem rails rbenv                                    
/Users/jagtarsingh/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/Users/jagtarsingh/.rbenv/shims/gem
/Users/jagtarsingh/.rbenv/shims/rails
/usr/local/bin/rbenv

Comment: And `rails -v` still shows an error @jagtar

Comment: yea, both rails -v & rails new myapp

Comment: You might  need to show he result of rerunning the rails install output. I’m guessing you have errors. I did following the guide. Set aside the app until rails can spit a version correctly. We know your app will fail if the base install isn’t done.

Comment: I have uninstalled the rbenv and rebooted the machine and reinstalled it worked.